# How to Copy and modify relative path in a single operation using msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

I am rather new to msbuild and boggling my mind on the following problem. Suppose I have the following file structure:

```
foo\bin\folder1_OK\file1.txt
foo\bin\folder1_OK\sub\file2.txt
foo\bin\folder2_NOK\file3.txt
bar\bin\folder3_OK\file4.txt
```

Using msbuild I would like to copy all folders with name ending with '_OK' and the underlying content to my drop location. I would also like to get rid of the intermediate 'bin' folder. In the example case I would like the output structure to be:

```
foo\folder1_OK\file1.txt
foo\folder1_OK\sub\file2.txt
bar\folder3_OK\file4.txt
```

Could this be achieved in a single operation? If the include attribute is '***_OK*' the RecursiveDir metadata still contains the bin folder. Is there a clever trick I can use to factor this out? Or should I better use a consecutive move task after the copy operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is generating a list of target path+file names based on input path+file names.

If you use MSBuild4 , you can use Property function to use regex to modify the directory names.

Then you can use Copy task to copy those files.

If you don't use msbuild4, you have to write a customized task to generate output list.